# How to return PDF contents in Rails without prompting the user to download the PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm trying to figure out how to render PDF contents back to the user so that the user's browser actually renders the PDF in the browser without prompting the user to download.

I have PDF documents stored in AWS S3 and, in the past, I would just simply redirect the user to the AWS S3 URL, which would cause their browser to render the PDF in the tab.

However, now I'd like to hide the AWS S3 URL, so I'm thinking about just grabbing the body of the PDF from the AWS S3 GET request and just simply rendering that back to the user. However, the only problem right now is that, when I do this, the user is prompted to download the PDF, rather than just loading it.

Here's what the current code looks like:

```
data = File.open("data.txt").read # contains the body of the AWS S3 PDF GET request, confirmed to be readable by PDF clients
send_data data, filename: "test.pdf", type: :pdf
```

However, when this happens, the user's browser just simply prompts them to download.

I have tried the following as well, but it just results in a file not found error (although the `data.txt` file does indeed exist):

```
send_file(data, filename: "test.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: :inline)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.pdf { send_file(data, filename: "test.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: :inline) }
end
```

no luck

How do I go about fixing this so that the contents are just rendered in the PDF format? Any alternative options would be greatly appreciated as well. I have tried just using an iframe, but keyboard shortcuts don't work (like cmd + s to save the PDF, etc.), so I figured just trying to render the PDF contents to the user would be a better way.

Comment: Have you registered "application/pdf" as a valid mimetype?

Comment: You need to pass a file path as the first parameter to `send_file`. If `data` is the binary data read from the file it will implicitly call `.to_s` on it and thus you get the error. You can use `send_data data, filename: "test.pdf", type: :pdf, disposition: :inline` but its really up to the client how it wants to deal with the PDF unless you want to go with one of those annoying integrated PDF readers like iPaper. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file

Comment: @MarkMerritt PDF is one the built in mime types. Try `Mime::Type.lookup('application/pdf')` if you don't want to take my word for it.

Comment: Using `send_data` worked for me. Thanks a lot!